# Scraping iframes without source with python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying scrape the contents of an iFrame (id="topic") from the following html file:
[image]

I tried using selenium and beautiful soup however, the code still doesn't see the elements inside the iFrame.

Is there a efficient way of scraping the contents of the mentioned iFrame from this
html file (preferably without using selenium) ?

Comment: I suggest you could post the url of the page so that it will be more convenient for us to help you.

Comment: Sure, you're right, 
please see the url: https://help.aprimo.com/#Marketing_Operations_Help/release_notes/release_notes_current_release_activity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the url of the `iframe`.
[image]

I found it is `https://help.aprimo.com/Content/Marketing_Operations_Help/release_notes/release_notes_current_release_activity.html`.

[image]

Then all the code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://help.aprimo.com/Content/Marketing_Operations_Help/release_notes/release_notes_current_release_activity.html"
response = requests.get(url=url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
# Then it is your work.
```

---

But I still suggest you use `selenium`.
You could use `driver.switch_to.frame("topic")` to switch to this `iframe` and then do what you want.

Comment: That works, thanks! 
Just one more question, where did You find the iFrame url? I tried looking for it but i didn't manage to find it.

Comment: @TheBvrtosz You could use `Chrome` console, and execute the js code in the picture I post.